# Filling the date which no record in the log data by pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a log table like

```
Category   User_id  0402_sales   0403_sales  0405_sales 
  Wine      999999      5            3           0  
  Beer      999999      5            0           0
  Beer      888888      3            2           3
```

I can only  make a table that is recorded in the log, but I want to fill the date even  without log.

For Example, our log begin from 4/1 and end on 4/6, I want the filled date table like below.

```
Category   User_id  0401_sales   0402_sales   0403_sales  0404_sales 0405_sales  0406_sales 
  Wine      999999      0            5           3            0          0           0
  Beer      999999      0            5           0            0          0           0
  Beer      888888      0            3           2            0          3           0
```

The point is check if the date from first to end day exist, if not add the date column  with values as 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reindex, axis=columns. If you want it to automate the newcols to be used for reindex, I would use regex to extract, compute the min and max, use pythons range to fill in and then reindex. This will give you minus some columns. Use combine_first to fix that. Code below

```
new_index=[f"0{num}_sales" for num in list(np.arange(df.columns.str.extract('(\d+)').dropna().min()[0].astype(int)-1,df.columns.str.extract('(\d+)').dropna().max()[0].astype(int)+2))]
df=df.reindex(new_index, axis="columns").fillna(0).combine_first(df)



     0401_sales  0402_sales  0403_sales  0404_sales  0405_sales  0406_sales  \
0         0.0           5           3         0.0           0         0.0   
1         0.0           5           0         0.0           0         0.0   
2         0.0           3           2         0.0           3         0.0   

  Category   User_id  
0     Wine  999999.0  
1     Beer  999999.0  
2     Beer  888888.0
```

Comment: Thank you, I know this solution, but if the log is from 1/1 and end 12/31, if any method to automatically fill the date

Comment: Thank you, as you first answered my question, and your answer can run in my enviorment, I will accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new index and rebuild the columns with it:

```
new_dates = [f"0{num}_sales" for num in range(401, 407)]

df = df.set_index(['Category', 'User_id'])

df.reindex(columns = new_dates, fill_value = 0).reset_index()

  Category  User_id  0401_sales  0402_sales  0403_sales  0404_sales  0405_sales  0406_sales
0     Wine   999999           0           5           3           0           0           0
1     Beer   999999           0           5           0           0           0           0
2     Beer   888888           0           3           2           0           3           0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a list of date with [pandas.date_range()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html). Then use `strftime()` to convert list of date with desired format.

```py
columns = [day + '_sales' for day in pd.date_range(start='2010-4-1', end='2010-4-10').strftime('%m%d')]
```

After that, remove the dates from `columns` which are already in `df.columns`. And assign the new columns value with default 0.

```py
columns = list(set(columns) - set(df.columns))
df[columns] = 0
```

At last, reorder the date columns with.

```py
df = df.reindex(df.columns.tolist()[:2] + sorted(df.columns.tolist()[2:]), axis=1)
# or
df = df[df.columns.tolist()[:2] + sorted(df.columns.tolist()[2:])]
```